# Google sheets IMPORTXML want to arrange the table data accordingly

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

I able to scrape the table data under this url (https://cryptorank.io/ath) but it is not arrange in a table form. How can I get the table nicely arrange in a table?

I tried:

```
=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML("https://cryptorank.io/ath", "//table"))

=IMPORTXML("https://cryptorank.io/ath", "//table")
```

But both are not in table form. Please advice how to get the data arrange in table form.

Comment: About `thanks.. Would like to know if I can list out more than 100 from the link? It seems like I can't go to page 2 and and get new data with importxml`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `How can I get the table nicely arrange in a table?`, understood that you wanted to retrieve the existing table. But from your reply, I understood that I misunderstood your question. In this case, I think that my answer has not resolved your actual question. So, I have to delete my answer. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Please don't apologize. The answer is correct to get the first 100 coins in the webpage. I also want to get the coins 101 to 200 in page but it does not work from my testing. Please help if you know how to get the xpath. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your 1st question of `The answer is correct to get the first 100 coins in the webpage.`, in this case, I think that my answer can be used. About your 2nd question of `I also want to get the coins 101 to 200 in page but it does not work from my testing.`, unfortunately, in this case, this cannot be achieved by IMPORTXML because the table of more than 100 items is not included in the HTML. By this, unfortunately, my answer was useful for only one of your 2 questions. I apologize for this.